# Can a `ServiceEntry` be applied to only 1 service?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We have a cluster with Istio, but there is this one condition, I can't find how to fulfill.

We need one of the services to have certain restrictions within the mesh as well, and to talk to one external endpoint. Through `Sidecar` object, I should be able to set the restrictions internally, but I don't know how to restrict to one external endpoint.

I can set the external endpoint in the `Sidecar` object as well, but I have to create a `ServiceEntry` anyways, in which case all the services can talk to that external endpoint.

It seems that what I need is to set a `ServiceEntry` for one specific service, but this is not possible. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, the first suggestion that comes to my mind is to configure [workload](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization) based authorization policies. So once You have external service added to registry with `ServiceEntry` You could restrict which specific workloads in the mesh would have access to that service.

Comment: I am not being able to do this. All tests failed so far. This seems to be mesh internal?

Comment: Yes, Your right. The istio telemetry is affected internally. Looks like this already has been covered on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24019). Did it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this [question on GitHub](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24019); to Istio team, and the only way to achieve this is putting the service in a different namespace, and make the `ServiceEntry` to apply to the workloads only in that namespace through `exportTo` parameter.

The `ServiceEntry` would look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: se-demo
spec:
  exportTo:
  - .                 # with ".", we are saying the ServiceEntry to only apply to the workloads in the same namespace.
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```